# Docker run failing when mounting host dir inside a container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, mount

I am trying to mount a directory from host to container and at the same time running jupyter from that directory. What am I doing wrong here that docker is complaining as file now found please?

docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter -v $HOME/mytensor:/tensor --name TensorFlow python:3.9 bash
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I tried removing the version of python but still same problem. I searched extensively online and couldnt get an answer.

Basically i want to mount that directory which is is a git clone where I have tensor files. At the same time, I want to run jupyter notebook where I can see the files and run them. With so many issues with apple:m1 processor and tensorflow, i thought going the docker route would be better but am i not surprised :)

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker run command syntax is

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

image name `tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter` should be after options (`-v`, `-p` `--name` et.al.) and before the command.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $HOME/mytensor:/tensor --name TensorFlow tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter bash
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working partially. I dont see jupyter running and also, i want python3.9 available in the docker env

Comment: Run without the bash at the end, tensorflow image has [default command](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/cpu-jupyter.Dockerfile#L81) to do the required

Comment: one problem i am facing with above is, i dont see my mounted directory in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: the default command runs `jupyter notebook` with `--notebook-dir=/tf` ,  plz mount your notebooks here to be available like `-v <local notebooks path>:/tf/notebooks `

Comment: That worked thanks. But, all the datascience tools are not available in this docker. So i am trying jupyter/tensorflow-notebook which has oython, pandas, tensorflow, etc. How do i know where does the root start ie similar to /tf in the earlier one?

Comment: I tried this as docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $HOME:/work/mytensor --name TensorFlow jupyter/tensorflow-notebook, and when i accessed the jupyter notebook, it showed work directory which comes by default but nothing inside there and i saw the following log 403 GET /api/sessions?_=1662528464430 (172.17.0.1) 22.65ms referer=http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree/mytensor

Comment: should be mounted to `/home/jovyan/work`, this is the default user home.